# Why getmethod returns null even though the method exists

Tags: java, class, reflection, methods

I have the following code:

```
String methodName = "main";
Method[] methods = classHandle.getMethods();
for (Method m : methods)
{
    System.out.println(m.getName().equals(methodName);
}
Method classMethod = null;
try
{
    classMethod = classHandle.getMethod(methodName);
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
System.out.println(classMethod == null);
```

The first print prints `true`, but the second one also prints `true`.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Calling `classHandle.getMethod` (assuming `classHandle` is a `Class`) when the method doesn't exist should result in a `NoSuchMethodException` being thrown, not `null` being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that 'classHandle' is a type of Class?

Your first loop only checks for the method name and does not care about method arguments.

The full signature of 'public Method getMethod(String name, Class... parameterTypes)' tells us that you are actually trying to find 0-argument method with name 'methodName'.

Are you sure that method with such a name and 0 arguments exists?

Comment: No, actually I'm searching for the main function of a class, which gets String[] args.

Comment: as in 'public static void main(String[] args)' ? Then you are missing parameter types specification in your 'getMethod('main', ...)' call.

Comment: In that case you need to do `classHandle.getMethod(methodName, String[].class);`

Comment: @R4J Yes, but on the JavaDoc it's written that when specifying no parameters it acts like an empty array.

Comment: @JohnDoe Please, show us how your 'main' method is declared.

Comment: @JohnDoe An empty array is still an array. `main` needs a `String[]`, even if the array is empty.

Comment: Yes - an array is an Object, event if it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

To get hold of static void main(String [] args) use the following

```
classHandle.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
```

Possible causes (written before we knew we were after static void main)

- Class.getMethod(name, parameters) returns only public methods, perhaps you want to use getDeclaredMethod(name, parameters) for a protected, default or private method
- Parameters don't match. Does "main" take any parameters? The parameters passed to getDeclaredMethod() or getMethod() have to match **exactly**.

Consider the following.

```
private class Horse {
    protected void makeNoise(int level) {
    }
}

// OK
System.out.println(Horse.class.getDeclaredMethod("makeNoise", new Class<?>[]{int.class})); 

 // throws NoSuchMethodException - parameters don't match
System.out.println(Horse.class.getDeclaredMethod("makeNoise")); 

// throws NoSuchMethodException, not a public method
System.out.println(Horse.class.getMethod("makeNoise", new Class<?>[]{int.class}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the parameters of the method do not match. You need to specify the parameter types in your call to getMethod().

Answer (score 0):

The [`getMethods` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--) returns an array of all `Method`s, and you are only checking the name.  It will return true for `main`, but `false` for all methods inherited from `Object`.

When you call the [`getMethod` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) with only the method name as a parameter, you are asking for a `Method` that takes no parameters.

But `main` takes one parameter, a `String[]`, so `getMethod` throws a `NoSuchMethodException`.  You're catching it, but doing nothing with it.  (You're "swallowing" the exception, generally a bad idea.)  So, `classMethod` remains `null` and `true` is outputted.

To find `main`, pass the parameter's type as an additional parameter:

```
Method classMethod = classHandle.getMethod(methodName, String[].class);
```